# cshtml razor views not recognised in VS Express, but OK in a higher version

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a console app with a razor view in it.  I have included what I understand to be all the references needed.  In VS2010 Ultimate, the yellow syntax highlighting and intellisense works.  When I open the exact same project on another machine with c# Express, the .cshtml has the 'unknown' icon instead of the cshtml one, and no highlighting/intellisense exists.

I've installed MVC3 on both, as well as downloaded/ referenced as needed:

RazorEngine.dll

System.Web.Razor

Any thoughts?

EDIT: I've now installed Visual Web Developer and then reinstalled MVC3, this has now made 'new MVC 3 project' available and the icon on .cshtml looks like it should.  However, still no intellisense.

Comment: I can assure you, MVC works in Express.  Are you sure it's VS 2010 Express?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need the WebDeveloper Express (not C# Express). But I'm not sure it handles Console apps.

The designer and template support is split up in the Express versions. So this mixed app might be difficult to get working.

Comment: The WebDeveloper Express edition does not support Console Apps unfortunatly, luckely you can have both versions of Visual Studio installed side-by-side though. Which allows you to do both.

Comment: Thanks guys.  Yes, the separation is a bit annoying.  Basically the only disadvantage is the lack of intellisense in the view templates, so it isn't too disastrous :)